# How to modify one condition inside a function without arg input?

Tags: php, function

I need to call a function that output a html. Inside this function, there's one condition to exclude one row from the html, I need this row. This condition is not an argument of the function. It's hard coded. So, I have to code my own, or, is there a way to modify this condition?

```
function get_media_item( $attachment_id, $args = null ) {
//....lots stuffs, then, arrive this part:
    $gallery = ( ( isset( $_REQUEST['tab'] ) && 'gallery' == $_REQUEST['tab'] ) || ( isset( $redir_tab ) && 'gallery' == $redir_tab ) );
    $order = '';

    foreach ( $form_fields as $key => $val ) {
        if ( 'menu_order' == $key ) {
            if ( $gallery )
                $order = "<div class='menu_order'> <input class='menu_order_input' type='text' id='attachments[$attachment_id][menu_order]' name='attachments[$attachment_id][menu_order]' value='" . esc_attr( $val['value'] ). "' /></div>";
            else
                $order = "<input type='hidden' name='attachments[$attachment_id][menu_order]' value='" . esc_attr( $val['value'] ) . "' />";

            unset( $form_fields['menu_order'] );
            break;
        }
    }
//... other stuffs
}
```

I need to call this function in other tabs, not "gallery" tab. So, I can't get the $order input box.

Comment: We can't read your mind or your code if you don't post it.

Comment: Anything is possible in the land of PHP! But seriously, paste some code and give us an example so we can understand what you're talking about, otherwise you're just going to get replies of "yes, using a text editor" or down voted

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to pass a parameter to the function(which would be recommended btw) to modify the condition, you can use globalize variable(or session).

Example:

```
function test(){
   global $instructions;

   if (isset($instructions['fetch'])){
      // new codes
   } else {
      // existing codes
   }

   return $result;
}

// implement:

$instructions = array();
$instructions['fetch'] = TRUE;
echo test();
```

Comment: Thanks! but the function is in wordpress core, I should not modify it directly. I can only work on whatever it provides.